# Establish UDP Connection from SWF File

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, udp, datagram, flash-builder4.5

I created a sample application to test UDP speed from my local machine to server.
to achieve same i created Action Script Project for Web using Adobe flash Builder where i am unable to get class flash.net.DataGramSocket.

and same package is available in Window based Action Script Project.

Why DataGramSocket is not available for web based project ?
is there any restriction ?

Comment: You cannot use any `AIR` code within browser SWF (only if you export as **.exe**, **air** or some Android **.apk** or as iOS app).

Answer (score 1):

In the [`flash.net` package description](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package-detail.html) there is an AIR icon near the   [`DatagramSocket`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/DatagramSocket.html) link meaning

> Only available in AIR runtime

Also the reference says:

> AIR profile support: This feature is supported on all desktop operating systems, on iOS (starting with AIR 3.8), and on Android (starting with AIR 3.8). This feature is not supported on AIR for TV devices. You can test for support at run time using the `DatagramSocket.isSupported` property. See AIR Profile Support for more information regarding API support across multiple profiles.